# Symfony3 Creating Service Error File Found but Class Not in it

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, namespaces

This is getting me crazy. I know the answer will be stupid but around 1 and half day on this I need to ask, English isn't my native language so be patient please. First of all I'm trying to write a simple service but continuously getting the error

> The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Services\Helpers" to be
>   defined in file
>   "C:\xampp7.1.7\htdocs\curso-fullstack\vendor\composer/../../src/AppBundle\Services\Helpers.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

on my *services.yml* file I got this

```
app.helpers:
  class: AppBundle\Services\Helpers
  arguments:
      - ["null"]
```

to define the service

my folder structure is *src/AppBundle/Services/Helpers*.php where I got the service class as follow

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Services\Helpers;

class Helpers {
    /* Funcion encargada de devolvernos un objeto json */
    public function jsonTemplate( $data ) {
        $normalizers = array( new GetSetMethodNormalizer() );
        $encoders    = array( "json" => new JsonEncoder() );

        $serializer = new Serializer( $normalizers, $encoders );
        $json       = $serializer->serialize( $data, 'json' );

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent( $json );
        $response->headers->set( "Content-Type", "application/json" );

        return $response;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the namespace to this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;
```

instead of this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services\Helpers;
```

Comment: I did and get a ServiceNotFoundException any suggestions?

Comment: Try to launch into your console "composer dump-autoload" if It doesn't work post your new error and your updates please into the question @GermánFonseca

Comment: ok that works please explain me... there was a cache of objects or something like that because I really clear cache in dev and prod environment

Comment: ok I have to add I just realize that I change a line in services.yml before it worked, if I change the line before I showed to you stop working again, code for service in services.yml corrected:  app.helpers:
      
 app.helpers:
      class: AppBundle\Services\Helpers
      public: true
      arguments:
          - ["null"]  so I put public: true because at the beggining of the file by _default is setting to false.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change **namespace** of  `class Helpers`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;
```

Comment: I did and get a ServiceNotFoundException any suggestions?